# Using storyboards for developing a static library in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I am a new iOS developer. I have to develop a static library. I have number of viewcontrollers and the flows between them are defined using a story board. I have created a two targets from my project. One is a static library and the other is a bundle. I use my bundle to include my story board in it. I have used this code to launch my first viewcontroller from the storybaord.

```
-(void)showFromViewController:(UIViewController *)vc{
    NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"storyBoards" withExtension:@"bundle"]];
    UIStoryboard * libStoryBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main1" bundle:bundle];
    ViewController1 * viewController = [libStoryBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController1"];
    [vc presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

vc is a ViewController that calls this function.

And yes ViewController has target membership with the static library.

However after including the '.a' and '.bundle' in another project and calling the above function it throws an error in the console Log.

`Unknown class ViewController1 in Interface Builder file.`

Can anyone suggest meright way to use a story board along with a static library. And if Yes then can you point out the right way to launch the first viewcontroller from the storyboard  who's class is included in the static library.

Comment: Are you certain you're getting the right bundle?  `[NSBundle bundleForClass:[ViewController1 class]]`

Comment: Yes i suppose. Because if I use the storybaord directly with the static library and reference the story board from th email bundle it still throws the same error.

Comment: It's not going to be in the main bundle.

Answer (score 0):

simply you can navigate like this

```
LoginViewController *loginVC=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginView"];
[self presentViewController:loginVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I have done the same thing. Since I am using the .a and storyboard in different project I have to retreive the story board from the bundle.

Comment: I didnt get what you mean by the above comment.

Comment: NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html" subdirectory:@"websiteDir"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:request];

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup. I have my main project, and I have a ModelController sub project which has a static library and a resources bundle that are used in my main project.

I created a storyboard and a test view controller and used your method above to load.

The only things that might catch you out are in your static library > target > build phases > copy headers > ensure you add your ViewController1.h file into this list.

Other than that, everything worked fine for me.

Comment: Can you specify why would that matter. Because I tried doing this still getting the same error. I suppose the error is because the ViewController1.m is not being loaded into the memory.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause here is that the view controller class (implemented in the static library) is stripped out by the linked, and therefore unavailable to the storyboard loader at runtime. I ran into this problem, and it went away when I made sure that the class in question was referenced from the code that was using the storyboard.

In my case that was easy because I needed to reference the class anyway (I just hadn't written that code yet), but I verified that `[ViewController class]` was enough to prevent the linker from erroneously stripping the class out.